# Get Item ID not working

Tags: client-object-model, caml-query

I'm trying to get the ID from a SharePoint list, however I cannot obtain it. `ctx_load(Include(ID))` does not seem to work. When I call `items.get_id();` it returns `undefined`. Also, the items object is undefined.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
function checkIfExists(keyword) {
    var listTitle = "Contact";
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var qry = new SP.CamlQuery();
    qry.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Title"/><Value Type="Text">' + keyword + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
    var items = list.getItems(qry);

    ctx.load(items,'Include(ID)');
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFail));             
}

function onSuccess(sender, args) {
  alert('ID: ' + items.get_id());
}

function onFail(sender, args) {
  alert('failed to get list. Error: ' + args.get_message());
}
```

Comment: what version of sharepoint are you using?

Comment: Hi Ryan, it's 2010 standard

Comment: You will need to iterate the items returned in your `items` varable

Answer (score 1):

Your `OnSuccess` must iterate the results:

```
function onSuccess(sender, args) {
    var listItemEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        alert('ID: ' + oListItem.get_id());
    }
}
```

Also, move the `OnSuccess` and `OnFail` inside of your main function (`checkIfExists`) to avoid the whole `items` object being undefined in the callback methods.

```
function checkIfExists(keyword) {
    var listTitle = "Contact";
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var qry = new SP.CamlQuery();
    qry.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Title"/><Value Type="Text">' + keyword + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
    var items = list.getItems(qry);

    ctx.load(items,'Include(ID)');
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFail));             


    function onSuccess(sender, args) {
      // Success as above
    }

    function onFail(sender, args) {
      alert('failed to get list. Error: ' + args.get_message());
    }
}
```

[Here's a good starting reference for JSOM development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx#BasicOps_SPListItemTasks)